# How to query on multiple columns with IN and partial string matching

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, sql-like

Let's say I have a table like:

```
col1 | col2 | col3|
---------------------
john | i1 | docs/name.txt 
john | i1 | images/prof.jpg 
marry| i2 | images/prof.jpg
```

I need to be able to query from the table by an array of tuples where each tuple is in the form `("john", "i1", "docs")` such that columns 1 and 2 match exactly and column 3 matches by a Regex (but I can also live with a LIKE).

So I want something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE (col1, col2, col3) IN (('john', 'i1', 'docs%'), ('marry', 'i2', 'images%'))
```

The array of tuples can be quite long (it comes from a javascript array).
There is a pk composed of all the columns. I would like it also to be used in the query.

Is there an elegant way to do this in Postgres?

Answer (score 1):

If you reformat your tuple generation in your Javascript to be an `JSON`ified array of arrays (which might be trivial depending on your use case, you can just pass your array to [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)), you can then use `jsonb_array_elements` in an `exists` subquery:

```
select t.* from tbl t where exists (select 1 from 
   jsonb_array_elements('[["john", "i1", "docs%"], ["marry", "i2", "images%"]]'::jsonb) v
   where (v.value -> 0)#>>'{}' = t.col1 
         and (v.value -> 1)#>>'{}' = t.col2 
         and t.col3 like (v.value -> 2)#>>'{}')
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/UgbFy2f4)

Comment: Thanks, this is elegant. Explain indicate that the like part doesn't use an index although I created a suitable index on col3. When I run a simple like query on col3, it does use the index.